# emacs uses different indentation based on what's already in file

Tags: python, emacs, tabs, formatting, indentation

I use 2-space indentation, no tabs.  When I open a file which already is indented with 8-spaces, that's what it continues to do.  I'd like emacs to change whats in the file (8-spaces) to **my setting** of 2-spaces.  Is there a way to do this?

This is how I've configured my tabs:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
```

If it's relevant, I'm working on python files.

Comment: How would emacs know that those 8 spaces are actually supposed to be a tab? I'm assuming it properly spaces REAL tab characters?

Comment: Also: note that using 2-space indentation in Python is against PEP8. You should use 4-space indents.

Comment: @AdamSmith presumably with a combination of seeing that it starts a line, and correctly parsing the code semantics...  And if PEP8 told you to jump off a bridge, would you?

Comment: @AdamSmith and anyway, it knows to correct 7 spaces to 8... so it seems to be recognizing all it needs to

Comment: No, though I'd probably throw the programmer before me whose code I have to maintain off that bridge if he didn't follow basic indentation guidelines :P

Comment: @AdamSmith ha, touche.  Is there a reason for 4-spaces?  I justed checked PEP8 and it doesn't say.

Comment: None other than consistency, like all of PEP8. It's the official style guide.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the tab-width controls how many characters the tab character will occupy when it is displayed. You need to set python-indent-offset. You should probably also do this in a mode hook as follows:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq python-indent-offset 2)))
```

TAre you using python.el or python-mode.el? If you don't know, which version of emacs are you using? python-mode.el was the default in versions of emacs that were released prior to the 24.2. I only tested this on python.el so it may need to be tweaked for python-mode.el

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know which version, but I'm using Emacs 23.1.1 (Not my fault!  Running on a remote cluster).  Probably for this reason, your suggestion isn't working...

Comment: When I do `M-x describe-mode`, it tells me 'Python Mode' but doesn't say where it's defined...

Comment: The variable that controls this in python-mode seems to be python-indent